# Showing json data in table view label

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So for i did :

I place one table view in view controller and i set the delegate and datasoure for that. Then i click on that table view and i went to right side of xcode tool to set DynamicPrototype and set prototype cell = 1.

What i need:

```
partner   gamer    pointer---> this is title i added using uiview above uitableview

   (lab1) (lab2)  (lab3)
    50      199     144
    80      112     11
    30      112     14
    50      100     199
    50      19      44
    200     500     100


Up to 25 Rows.
```

lab1, lab2, lab3 are three labels that i created in `Table.xib`

Then i create a `subclass` of `uitableviewcell`.Then here is that code:

**Table.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface TableView : UITableViewCell



    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lab1;

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lab2;


    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lab3;
    @end
```

**Table.m**

```
#import "TableView.h"

@implementation TableView
@synthesize lab1 = _lab1;
@synthesize lab2 = _lab2;
@synthesize lab3 = _lab3;


- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

And i edited all code in my `viewcontroller.m` and here i added some `json` data to that:

**Viewcontroller.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TableView.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController
{


    NSArray *jsonObject;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //NSArray *jsonObject;
    jsonObject = @[
                   @{
                       @"partner": @"50",
                       @"gamer": @"199",
                       @"pointer": @"144"

                   },
                   @{
                       @"partner": @"80",
                       @"gamer": @"112",
                       @"pointer": @"11"                   },
                   @{
                       @"partner": @"30",
                       @"gamer": @"112",
                       @"pointer": @"14"


                   },
                   @{
                       @"partner": @"50",
                       @"gamer": @"100",
                       @"pointer": @"199"
                   },
                  @{
                       @"partner": @"50",
                       @"gamer": @"19",
                       @"pointer": @"44"

                   },
                   @{
                       @"partner": @"200",
                       @"gamer": @"500",
                       @"pointer": @"100"
                   }
                   ];

    NSError *err;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];



    NSString * jsonString=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",jsonString);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [jsonObject count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Tabel" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

//    cell.lab1.text = [jsonObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//cell.lab2.text = [jsonObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 25;
}

@end
```

Actually i need to show the json date to my `uitableview` as i showed in my above example.

In this below method i dont know how to add my 3 label.text to upgrade my json value to display in table view:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Tabel" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

//    cell.lab1.text = [jsonObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//cell.lab2.text = [jsonObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Please help me to solve.. i followed this 2 tutorial [Tutorial 1](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/) [tutorial2][2]

Here is my project link [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nzw8v73rwz0v9di/jsonTableView.zip?dl=0)

I am beginner and self learning ios. please help me to get that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link of your update code its fixed and working.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jvcmpkywtrcr2p3/jsonTableView%202.zip?dl=0

Please search, read the answers carefully and than ask questions here.

Comment: yes its working perfect . and one more question i forgot to add. i  ned to keep a radio button at left side and only one row should select at a time. please help me to do that.....that will be more help full

Comment: Add that button in your table cell xib and check every time you click on the button if other is selected or not you can go for radio button in ios tutorials online.

Comment: sure will check. if i not get i will post my another question link .please do help if i miss any code. because i already tried i dint get so only

Comment: Please help me i tried but not able to get select and sedelect my radio button..here is my post       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574016/radio-button-in-tableview-cell

Comment: They gave some solution but i need only one button should select at a time and when i select one button then i scroll down my selected button is again automatically de select..Here my post link please help me                             http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574016/radio-button-in-tableview-cell/34574244#