# Radio button in tableview Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

Here I am using subclass of `UITableviewcell` as `Tableview`. And I am creating some dummy json value and I am passing to the label in my tableview cell.

And also i added one button in my `Tabelview.xib` at `left side`. That button will act as radiobutton to check and uncheck. Now when I run my all table view are showing uncheck image button. How can I check or uncheck?

Here is my code:

`Tableview.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableView : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lab1;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lab2;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lab3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *checkBtn;


@end
```

`Tableview.m`

```
#import "TableView.h"

@implementation TableView
@synthesize lab1 = _lab1;
@synthesize lab2 = _lab2;
@synthesize lab3 = _lab3;
@synthesize checkBtn;



- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

**Viewcontroller.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TableView.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController
{


    NSArray *jsonObject;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //NSArray *jsonObject;
    jsonObject = @[
                   @{
                       @"partner": @"50",
                       @"gamer": @"199",
                       @"pointer": @"144"

                   },
                   @{
                       @"partner": @"80",
                       @"gamer": @"112",
                       @"pointer": @"11"                   },
                   @{
                       @"partner": @"30",
                       @"gamer": @"112",
                       @"pointer": @"14"


                   },
                   @{
                       @"partner": @"50",
                       @"gamer": @"100",
                       @"pointer": @"199"
                   },
                  @{
                       @"partner": @"50",
                       @"gamer": @"19",
                       @"pointer": @"44"

                   },
                   @{
                       @"partner": @"2000",
                       @"gamer": @"500",
                       @"pointer": @"1000"
                   }
                   ];

    NSError *err;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];



    NSString * jsonString=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",jsonString);




}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [jsonObject count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableView";
    TableView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.lab1.text = [jsonObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"gamer"];
    cell.lab2.text = [jsonObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"partner"];
    cell.lab3.text = [jsonObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"pointer"];


    return cell;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 78;
}
```

At only one radio button should check and other rows radiobutton are should uncheck.

I used two image:

1. selectBtn.png
2. deselectBtn.png

What am I missing? I tried these steps to added in my projects but I am a beginner so not able to do perfectly and getting more crash.

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *radioButtonArray;
}

@property (nonatomic ,retain)NSMutableArray *radioButtonArray;
in tableviewController.h.m

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    radioButtonArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i ++) {
        UIButton *radioButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [radioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [radioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-on.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [radioButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
        [radioButton addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [radioButtonArray addObject:radioButton];
    }
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
and give it a (IBAction) void

- (IBAction)radioButtonPressed:(UIButton *)button{
    [button setSelected:YES];
    // Unselect all others.
    for (UIButton *other in radioButtonArray) {
        if (other != button) {
            other.selected=NO;
        }
    }
}
```

[Here is my project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nzw8v73rwz0v9di/jsonTableView.zip?dl=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use an array to save all the cells. and on -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath delegate to get which row is selected and make the others rows button and select the selected row button.

I have done this for you i am suggesting you to use the logics and don't post every issue you are facing here.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/j02yotvevxfp821/jsonTableView%203.zip?dl=0

Comment: but when scroll back and come i can't see my already selected radio button

Comment: And one more think. i need to select radio button . not a table view cell.......After i scroll down my selected button is automatically deselecting

Comment: download new code i have updated the link.  To not select the row you can make the property of the cell in selection section none.

Comment: to select the button instead of selection my cell. i select my cell and gave `selection = none` is there any idea or method to select direcly the button instead of selecting the cell

Comment: Follow this link to https://www.dropbox.com/s/odshtv0nw0svuyg/Screen%20Shot%202016-01-03%20at%203.34.16%20PM.png?dl=0
You are using table view so you have to go with Table cell selection process.

Comment: yes i already gave that to none. but i am asking instead of selecting row ,if possible to select directly the radio button to check and uncheck

Answer (score 0):

At first Connect **IBOutlet**  **checkBtn** button

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableView";
TableView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

cell.lab1.text = [jsonObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"gamer"];
cell.lab2.text = [jsonObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"partner"];
cell.lab3.text = [jsonObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"pointer"];

[cell.checkBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

return cell;
}

//Radio button pressed 

-(void)radioButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
if( [[btn imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deselectBtn"]]){
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectBtn"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}else{
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deselectBtn"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
}
```

Comment: when i select one buton then i scroll back my selected button is automatically uncheck...  And also only one row Radio button should select then other should deselect

Comment: Please help me..1. At a time only one button should select in one row. 2. And when i select one button then when i  scroll down and come back my selected button is deselected automatically ,